# why other dropdownlists in the page are renew when i click one dropdownlist in the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have many dropdown lists in my page and I have written Javascript for three of them. Here is my javascript;

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function getSelectValue() {
        var selectedValue = document.getElementById("egitimkonusu").value;
        window.location.href = "egitim?deger=" + selectedValue;
        return selectedValue;
    }

    function getSelectValue2() {
        var selectedValue2 = document.getElementById("eklenecek").value;
        window.location.href = "/egitim?deger="+ getSelectValue() +"&"+"?eklenecekid=" + selectedValue2;
    }

    function getSelectValue3() {
        var selectedValue3=document.getElementById("secili").value;
        window.location.href="/egitim?deger="+ getSelectValue() +"&"+"?silinecekid="+selectedValue3;
    }
</script>
```

My question is when I click any option in `dropdownlist(secili,egitimkonusu,eklenecek)` other dropdownlists's selected values get empty. I guess the page is being renewed. I don't want the page to renew when I click some value in `dropdownlist`. Can anyone help me? I have just started to learn. 
Thanks for any help

Comment: *"I guess the page is being renewed."* Yes, you're right, that's why. *"I dont want the page to renew when i click some value in dropdownlist."* In that case, remove the code setting `window.location.href`, since that's what's reloading the page. Instead, perhaps have a button the user clicks that sets the new URL with all of the selected values.

Comment: You are reloading the page with `window.location.href`. That might be the cause.. How you are loading the values bdw?

Comment: I need 'deger' value coming from window.location.href. I get these option values at the same page as $deger=( Get['deger']). Can i get the value when i click any option in dropdownlist without refreshing ?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = "egitim?deger=" + selectedValue;
```

This line is mess according to me. It must be refreshing the page every time.

Don't you want to set `id` or a `class` for the selected value?

something like this?

```
$('#displayid').append('<option value='+abx+'>'+xyz+'</option>');
```